# Showing flash messages in DJango with close button

Tags: python, django, django-views, web2py, flash-message

I want to display flash messages in Django with the close button.
Existing message framework in Django allows to display messages and does not allow to close it.

As an example, web2py provides such flash messages. I am looking for similar functionality in Django.

[image: Flash Message in web2py]

If it can be done with few lines of code , it would be great. 
I do not want to add any other libraries or framework on top of Django.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: r u using bootstrap

Comment: Yes , I am using bootstrap.
I found solution using bootstrap only ! :)

Comment: What if I want to flash it for fixed time ?

Comment: you can do it using jquery

Comment: How ?
can you give some pointers ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was unaware that such thing can be solved using boot-strap !

I did something like this :

```
{% if messages %}
  {% for msg in messages %}
    <div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissable">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
      {{msg.message}}
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

It shows message like :
[image: Flash Message in Django]

Answer (score 4):

in html template add this jquery timeout function

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
window.setTimeout(function() {
  $(".alert").fadeTo(500, 0).slideUp(500, function(){
      $(this).remove();
  });
}, 5000);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Nice! I like this for certain message classes like success. Otherwise, they I would use the close method because you want it to hang around to make sure the user has a chance to digest the alert.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using bootstrap 5 use this.

```
<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
  <strong>Holy guacamole!</strong> You should check in on some of those fields below.
  <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
</div>
```

In older versions of bootstrap if you have
`data-dismiss="alert"`
change this to

```
data-bs-dismiss="alert"
```

for more docs [visit bootstrap 5 Dismissing](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/alerts/#dismissing)

Answer (score 2):

Q. Dismiss Button is not working in alert message in django python

Ans:
data-**bs**-dismiss="alert" ,this is the change in Bootstrap 5 i.e. in another bootstrap version there is **data-dismiss="alert"** , but in bootstrap 5 there is **bs** added so add **bs** like this
**data-bs-dismiss="alert"**

Answer (score 0):

If you are using materializecss you can take the help of chip

```
 <div class="chip" style="display: contents;">
    <div class="card-panel red darken-1 ">
        <i class="material-icons white-text">info</i>
        <span class="white-text text-darken-2" style="vertical-align: super; font-size: large;">
            {{message}}
        </span>
       <i class="close material-icons white-text right">close</i>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As **@jeevu94** pointed out correctly, I would suggest using it in a more DRY way that fits each message's setup.

```
{% if messages %}

{% for message in messages %}

<div class="container-fluid p-0">
  <div class="alert {{ message.tags }} alert-dismissible" role="alert" >
    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="x"></button>
    {{ message }}
  </div>
</div>

{% endfor %}

{% endif %}
```